# JavaScript Visual Studio Code settings

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have used Brackets as a JavaScript editor. Highlighting syntax errors was poor.
I started exploring JSHint when somebody suggested that I try **"Visual Studio Code"**.
So I downloaded VSCode and typed this into the file test.js:

```
var y prompt(Enter a number);
Y=10;
y=y+5
alert(x);
```

There is hardly any syntax checking at all. 'a number' is underlined. That's it. No indication that Y has not been defined on line 2. Or line 3 has missing semi-colon. Or that `x` is undefined on line 4.

Do I need to change some VSCode settings?

Or do I need add a JSHint linter extension?

Comment: "No indication that Y has not been defined on line 2" -- should it have been? "Or line 3 has missing semi-colon" --- should it have? "Or that x is undefined on line 4." --- you don't know that statically. You're confusing syntax with style and runtime errors.

Comment: I guess you have to fix first line first

Comment: You might try VSCode TypeScript.  Try your example code at : http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: `prompt("Enter a number");`

Answer (score 0):

Because VSCode does not come with a linter, you need to install a package into VSCode:
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.jshint

Also, with JavaScript, declaring a variable without `var` will work, it's just not a good way to do it for various reasons. So again, this is a linting issue.

Semicolons are not mandatory, again, a linting issue.